# Hide sites from Hot Network Questions section

Tags: script, questions

**Screenshot**

[image: Sites marked as hidden]

**About**

The 'Hot Network Questions' section has questions from websites which are not very interesting for me so with this script you can:

- Hide questions from those websites
- Stop hiding the site if you change your mind
- The settings are stored per browser so they work on all sites of StackExchange network

**Download**

[install/update script](https://github.com/Giorgi/SE-Hot-Network-Questions-Filter/raw/master/hot-sites.user.js) - [view source](https://github.com/Giorgi/SE-Hot-Network-Questions-Filter/blob/master/hot-sites.user.js)

**Platform**

I have tested this script in Chrome with Tampermonkey and Firefox with Greasemonkey on Windows 7.

**Contact**
This script was created by Giorgi Dalakishvili. [Report bugs and request new features at Github.](https://github.com/Giorgi/SE-Hot-Network-Questions-Filter/issues)